# SQL Server CE format query

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

The following query works fine in MS Access or SQL Server:

```
SELECT FORMAT(a.Data, "dd/MM/yyyy") as Data 
FROM mytable
```

as I got this error:

> ErrorMessage: The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = ,Column name = dd/MM/yyyy ]

But not on SQL Server CE. I could not find any documentation about this, any hints?

Comment: I doubt this works anywhere. You haven't aliased your table as `a`.

Comment: I can see this working on MS Access, but not SQL Server.  Use single quotes for strings.

Comment: This is a legacy project. The column "Data" is a varchar, and it contains date as 'yyyy-DD-mm' .  I just want to format them as 'dd/MM/yyyy'. I forgot to put the alias on the main table but it's a typo